# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ValuesController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I'm working with .NET and getting this error, It's my first time doing this so I'm really not sure how to fix this. I have two files that I'm working with, one is called "UnitTest1.cs" which is where the error is occurring and it's saying it occurs on line 12 in regards to the 'ValuesController' and that code is right here

```
using System;
using Xunit;
using SimpleAPI.Controllers;



namespace SimpleAPI.Test
{

    public class UnitTest1
    {   
        ValuesController controller = new ValuesController();
        [Fact]
        public void GetReturnsMyName()
        {
            var returnValue = controller.Get(1);
            Assert.Equal("Mitchell Privett", returnValue.Value);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {

         }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this other file affects it or not, but it's in the same directory and it's called SimpleAPI.Test.csproj and the code for that is here:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\SimpleAPI\SImpleAPI.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: You should open the project by the opening the project file and not the cs file.  There looks like there is a 2nd project that is required that need to be in a relative folder to the first : "..\..\src\SimpleAPI\SImpleAPI.csproj"

Answer (score 1):

The class `ValuesController` is not defined.
Include the according library with the `using` statement:

```
using MyLibraryThatContainsValuesController;
```

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but how do I find the library it uses?

Comment: either `ValuesController`  is defined in an external library, then you get it from the documentation of the class. if it is a class you have built yourself, it is the namespace in which the class is defined. If you run with a smart IDE like visual studio, having the cursor on the class name and pressing alt+enter might provide you the missing entry.

Answer (score 1):

In your test project, add a project reference to your main project (SimpleAPI) if you haven't done already. If you're using Visual Studio Community, you can do so by right clicking on your test project file (SimpleAPI.Test) in the solution explorer -> Add -> Project Reference... -> mark the checkbox next to the SimpleAPI -> click OK

If the problem's still there, go back to your test project and add a `using` statement refering to the namespace of the `ValuesController` class. If you don't know the namespace, open your `ValuesController` class. On top of the code (after `using` statements) you'll see something like:

```
namespace SimpleAPI.Controllers
```

There's your namespace!